# Code in docker updated but built code does not show changes

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code

I am working with a reactjs and python app which I installed in Docker.
To accomplish this I, Downloaded Docker Deskstop, pulled an image, and proceeded with my installation. Upon completion of everything in Docker, I downloaded Remote Containers and connected my VSCode to My docker by selecting "Attach to running container.

After doing this, I can launch the python application and a port pops up to run the application in my browser. All seems to be fine except when I make edits, If I make an edit it changes in VSCode and navigate to the folder in the file in ubuntu (in docker) the change is there.

The problem I am experiencing is, that change is not reflected when I launch the app. And it worked initially. I run `yarn build` which is defined as `{ "scripts": { "build": "rm -rf build/* && parcel build -d build src/index.html",`
in the package.json and restart the server enviroment.

However, I cannot get my new changes to show, appreciate if assistance could be given with this issue.

Comment: are you trying to save the changes in a image or volume?

Comment: @mapa0402 container

Comment: a container is based on an image, so if you want to see new changes in the container you have to build and run it again.

Comment: @mapa0402 I see the new changes in the container, however the code reactjs built doesnt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should mount a volume for your container like this :

```sh
docker run -v /somewhere_in_host/html:/data/html
```

Now you can see changes in real time. Check [this tutorial](https://www.section.io/engineering-education/how-to-share-data-between-a-docker-container-and-the-host-computer/) for more information.

Comment: Can I still do this, even if the container and image were created in Docker Desktop?

Comment: Check [here](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/01/13/docker-mount-dynamic-volumes/) @Niana